# The name of this interface?

Tags: mac, optical-drive, pata, terminology, connector

What's the name of that black connector from MacBook 2.1?

**edit:** The black connector is used to connect optical drive. I've read on late Macs, it's a SATA interface, which someone replace the optical drive with a SATA HDD. So just want to know whether my interface is.

[image: What's that black thing?]

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it did not have a name, only a numerical description... but I have no idea.

Comment: Found in your laptop, to connect HD or CD? May be proprietary, and no popular name.

Comment: Did you make this picture yourself, or did you find it in some ad at 
eCRATER?

Comment: More information please: from what machine (brand, model?), from what part of the machine (near the cpu, near the disk?), is this a 1996 or a 2009 machine, what does the other side of the card look like?

Comment: And how big is it? And doe the small light-grey parts on the bottom left and right indicate something is broken, or is that just the light on some inclined part?

Comment: So, it's solved now?

Comment: @Arjan, I think the 'small-gray-parts' are light reflecting on the notches at the two edges. Those notches confused me for a while. Reminded me of older parallel connectors with alignment notches on the edges. Which is part of the reason I had doubts.

Comment: (@nik, that's correct; see the much better picture through the link at Nicolas' answer.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Your picture is not too good

   - You have not given any notes about where you got this from

I'd hazard a guess that its a SCSI connector.
There are 25 pins on each side (i think) and it looks like it might go well with
the `Centronics SCSI 50pin` connector from the link I give below.
<sup>don't have enough confidence on it yet... the plastics do not match too well.</sup>

This [cheat-sheet reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vgow.jpg) should help you try matching better,
and also give you suggestions how to take connector pictures `:-)`
And, here is a link to the [Apple Mac SCSI FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3076?viewlocale=en_US#faq4) for further perusal.
Look for the Internal 50pin SCSI interface.

---

**Update**: First-hand-information from `kinokijuf` indicates it is a PATA connector.
You should re-check based on this detail.

Comment: +1 for counting the solder-thingies. 25 indeed :-)

Comment: Not sure about your answer. But the reference you give is pretty good. Thanks.

Comment: -1 It’s not SCSI, it’s PATA. Slimline drives used this wierd connecter (i have one of these lying around).

Answer (score 2):

Probably a internal SATA connector for the SuperDrive (DVD burner).

http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Optical-Drive-Cable/IF186-022

[iFixit](http://ifixit.com) is my one-stop place for any teardowns/information on taking apart/repairing Apple products.

I hazarded a guess based on your model description (Macbook 2,1).

Answer (score 1):

Now it seems a PATA connector to the optical drive. Because this whole thing might be a converter, so not sure what's the interface onboard yet.

Comment: Welcome at Super User, but: please read the FAQs and do not ignore *"Are you sure you want to answer your own question? If you're responding to answers left on your question, use the comments link under each answer."* This is not a forum. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm it’s PATA. I have one of those old drives running around.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a internal sata connector, upside down.

But more information would be really helpful.  What was this taken out of?  What was it connected to?